# Cisco wireless: APs with and without CleanAir

Tags: cisco, wireless

We have a Cisco 5508 wireless controller, Cisco Prime NCS, and the Cisco MSE.  Our company needs three SSIDs, and each SSID must have a different Vlan.  We have a mixture of Cisco 1242 and Cisco 3602i APs; our environment is mostly Windows 7.  We want to use the CleanAir technology on the 3602i APs.

Is there a problem using CleanAir on the 3602i APs in the same building with the 1242 APs, which don't have CleanAir?  If it's ok to do this, how do I set CleanAir up on the 3602i and no CleanAir on the 1242 APs?

Are we able to mix 1242 APs with CleanAir 3602i APs on the same SSID?  If so, how do I set this up?  Are there any problems to watch out for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clean Air is enabled by default on the radios of AP that support Clean Air. It is primarily hardware based so it is 'bound' to a radio, not SSID. You can mix them (APs), but only the ones with Clean Air will do spectrum monitoring on the channel they are on and report configured events.

You enable Clean Air for `a/n` and `b/g/n` under the wireless tab at your WLC. You can configure it to report detected interference and tune what type of interference to ignore or detect. Also you can disable Clean Air on AP basis, you should see Clean Air capable field somewhere on the configuration page for the AP. This will override the global WLC setting for that AP since it is more specific.

Comment: And the 1242 APs should be identified as friendly AP's in the rogue AP detection so Clean Air stops complaining about them.